# How to implement a C++ plugin in a standard compliant way?

Tags: c++, linux, plugins, extern, unique-ptr

I did look around on SO and elsewhere, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer to this pretty standard question. I'm particularly interested in linux and standard compliance. I came accross the following approach

`file plugin.h`  part of the library

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
/// defines an interface to be implemented by a plugin
struct PluginBase
{
  virtual~PluginBase() {}
  virtual double calc(double) const = 0;
};
/// loads a plugin
/// \param[in] file  shared object file to load and find plugin in
/// \param[in] strg  data for initialising the plugin
std::unique_ptr<PluginBase> load_plugin(std::string const&file, std::string const&strg);
extern "C" {
  /// to be implemented with plugin
  /// \param[in] strg  data for initialising the plugin
  std::unique_ptr<PluginBase> create_plugin(std::string const&strg);
}
```

`file plugin.cc`  part of the library

```
#include "plugin.h"
#include <cassert>
extern "C" {
#include <dlfcn.h> // dlopen() dlsym()
  std::unique_ptr<PluginBase>(*create_ptr)(std::string const&);
}
std::unique_ptr<PluginBase> load_plugin(std::string const&file,
                                        std::string const&strg)
{
  auto handle = dlopen(file.c_str(),RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL);
  assert(handle);                                  // in lieu of proper error handling
  auto func_ptr = dlsym(handle,"create_plugin");
  assert(func_ptr);                                // ditto
  return reinterpret_cast<create_ptr>(func_ptr)(strg);
}
```

`file some_plugin.cc`  not part of the library

```
#include "plugin.h"
struct PluginImpl : PluginBase
{
  PluginImpl(std::string const&);
  double calc(double) const override;
};
/// has extern "C" linkage
std::unique_ptr<PluginBase> create_plugin(std::string const&strg)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<PluginBase>(new PluginImpl(strg));
}
```

Is this way of doing things correct and standard compliant? In particular, can I return `std::unique_ptr<>` from a function with `extern "C"` linkage? and can such a function take a const reference argument? Do I have to declare the `create_ptr` as `extern "C"` (in file `plugin.cc`)? Can I avoid `extern "C"` and directly obtain the C++ symbols ([this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/48TbqMoL/) discusses this for windows, not linux, and is compiler specific)?

Comment: It's finally going to get compiler/runtime environment specific, because the c++ standards don't rely on any concepts like static or dynamic linkage.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no standards for plug-ins.  There is also no compliance for plug-ins.  It's all platform and OS specific.

Answer (score 3):

1. Linkage has nothing to do with types. It is solely a property of *names*.
2. Dynamic loading the way you do it is not specified by the C++ Standard; specifically, the reinterpret cast from a void pointer to a function pointer is unspecified. There are other subtle issues regarding static initializers and sharing static objects that aren't specified properly and can surprise you.
3. However, the Posix standard documents `<dlfcn.h>` and also requires that the cast Does What You Think, so your code is Posix compliant and should work on any Posix-compliant operating system.
4. There is no universal recipe for finding the symbol names. If you use C linkage, you need to consult your platform's C ABI; if you want to use C++ linkage, you need to consult your C++ ABI. Neither is universal or fixed, though there is a lot more cross-platform agreement on what the C ABI looks like than for C++. (Specifically, it should be possible to emit symbols in the C ABI in such a fashion that mangled function names are identical to their names in the source code.)